# How do I enable a form button when a calculated control changes value?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a MS-Access form with a calculated text box/control named "txtValidation" that changes based on some selections I make in four combo boxes on my form. The result in the text box will end up displaying either "Validated" or "Selection validated".
On the same form I have a button named "btnSave" which is disabled when the form opens. I want the value "Validated" in txtValidation to trigger the enabling of btnSave. So far I have this, but it doesn't work;

```
Private Sub txtValidation_Change()

If Me.txtValidation.Value = "Selection validated" Then

Me.btnSave.Enabled = True

End If

End Sub
```

Anyone who can help me please?

Comment: Controls in Access do not fire events (`Change()`, `AfterUpdate()` etc) when their value changes via code, as in your example the calculated control. You need to handle it on the `AfterUpdate()` event of the combo-boxes (user change, the event will fire).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all of you for the assistance! I solved the issue by taking Kostas advise, and fire the event on the AfterUpdate of each combo box;

```
Private Sub cboDestination_AfterUpdate()

Me.cboLane.Requery

Me.cboHaulier.Requery

Me.cboVehicle.Requery

Me.Refresh

If Me.txtValidation.Value = "Selection validated" Then

Me.btnSave.Enabled = True

Else

Me.btnSave.Enabled = False

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Or in a single line: `Me.btnSave.Enabled = Me.txtValidation.Value = "Selection validated"`. The right hand side is always evaluated first.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for `Validated` instead of `Selection validated`

```
If Me.txtValidation.Value = "Validated" Then
```